# audio playslist uwp mediaelement c#

Tags: c#, uwp, mediaelement

store the files 
        `ObservableCollection<StorageFile> files;`

```
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    files = new ObservableCollection<StorageFile>();
    _fileList.ItemsSource = files;
    this.DataContext = this;
}
```

open file location. The file location opens and the audio is added to the list

```
async private System.Threading.Tasks.Task AddMedia()
{
    //Create a new picker
    var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();

    //Add filetype filters. 

    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".wav");


    //Set picker start location to the video library
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.MusicLibrary;

    //Retrieve single file from picker
    StorageFile file;
    file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();

    if (file != null)
    {
        files.Add(file);
        mediaElement.Play();
    }

}
```

choose file from listview
the file plays but as soon as it ends it doesnt play the next one in the list. I want to play the next one in the list automatically but i am struggling with it please help

```
private async void _fileList_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{   
    var storageitem = e.ClickedItem as StorageFile;
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await 
    storageitem.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    mediaElement.SetSource(stream, storageitem.ContentType);
    this.txt_song.Text = "Now playing: " + storageitem.Name;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two MediaElements to implement your requirement.

> One solution is to use two MediaElements. One MediaElemet is always playing and the second is opening and loading the next track in the background ready to start playback as soon as it is needed. When one playlist item ends we can immediately start playback of the next. Then the one that was just playing starts to queue the next item. Sounds simple right?
>
> The key to making any playlist solution work with the MediaElement is
>   to handle the “MediaEnded” event. When we receive this event we know
>   that the item is done playing. We can then check the playlist and
>   start the next item playing. Luckily unlike with the Media Player SDK,
>   the MediaElement guarantees that we will always get the “MediaEnded”
>   event. Without this a playlist solution would be
>   impossible.

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2014/07/11/multi-mediaelement-a-playlist-solution-next-item-no-waiting/

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to read and answer my question

Answer (score 0):

you should use [MediaPlaybackList](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/media-playback-with-mediasource#play-a-list-of-media-items-with-mediaplaybacklist) for creating music playlists and easily managing them, it helps you to move to next media file or the previous one very easily, supports gap-less playback, and in the long term it will make your life very easier to control a playlist fully. It is best if you use it with the ui control [MediaPlayerElement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.mediaplayerelement)

Comment: Thank you for the advice i appreciate it very much!

Comment: @JuaniqueVoogt if it solves your problem please consider marking the answer and upvoting it. thanks.

Comment: There was a typo in our formative for which it had to be designed for windows 8.1 and not windows 10. Windows 8 does not support the mediaplayerelement but since its fixed we can use it. Thank you very much